# Excel dates are not from the XXI century

Tags: excel-formula

I have a problem with dates in excel.

I should change a format: `140506 (yymmdd)` into `2014-05-06`, I have created a new column and used the

formula: `=DATE(LEFT(A3;2); MID(A3;3;2); RIGHT(A3;2))`  but my date has a year from  19th century -> `1914-05-06`. Could you help me with my task? Regards, K.

Comment: Thank you Richard! It's working :)

Answer (score 2):

`=DATE("20"&LEFT(A3;2);`

If you have some dates from the 20th century then instead try something like `=DATE(IF(LEFT(A3;2)>50;LEFT(A3;2);"20"&LEFT(A3;2));`